# Im trying to do bottomSheet on react native but ım getting an error. Error is: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ref<unknown> | undefined'

Tags: react-native, mobile

```
<BottomSheet
      bottomSheerColor="#FFFFFF"
      ref="BottomSheet"
      initialPosition={'50%'} 
      snapPoints={['50%', '100%']}
      isBackDrop={true}
      isBackDropDismissByPress={true}
      backDropColor="red"             //======> this prop will change color of backdrop
      
      header={
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Header</Text>
        </View>
      }
      body={
        <View style={styles.body}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Body</Text>
        </View>
      }
    />
```

the problem line is:  ref="BottomSheet"

this ref is main problem

how can i fix this ?

Comment: you can use useRef() hook to apply refs

Answer (score 0):

String refs are legacy implementation. Please use the `useRef` hook to manage ref.

```js
const bottomsheetRef = React.useRef(null)

....

<BottomSheet
  ref={bottomsheetRef}
/>
```

Now to access the `ref`,  do

```js
bottomsheetRef.current
```

Comment: const bottomSheet = useRef();
   const sheetRef = React.useRef(null); i wrote thoso and write  <BottomSheet
        ref={sheetRef}
        snapPoints={[450, 300, 0]}
        borderRadius={10}
       
      />

Comment: but it say invalid hook call to me

Comment: can you post those code?

Comment: i did what u say and new error: Type '{ children: Element; ref: null; visible: boolean; onBackButtonPress: () => void; onBackdropPress: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children: ReactChild | ReactChild[]; } & BottomSheetProps'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children: ReactChild | ReactChild[]; } & BottomSheetProps'.

Comment: I still dont see you using the useRef.

Comment: const bottomsheetRef = React.useRef(null) i did but ref say now its null

Comment: could you please paste a minimal reproducible example.